# hot standby .NET server app

Tags: .net, redundancy

Earlier we used CORBA to achieve hot standby redundancy in our dual server setup. Now I have .NET platform to do the same. What I want is a dual server redundant set up in which if one server goes down, the other one should take over immediately. This should happen transparent to the client. What I need is a middleware that should handle such thing out of the box.

Please tell me if needed further information.

Thanks and regards,
Abhishek

Comment: Probably better suited to serverfault, HA/Redundancy is better handled at the OS level.

Comment: @booya can you be more specific? I have an object on one machine, same object should be in sync on other machine. Client calls a method on one object only the active one should respond. If active application crashes, then the passive one should take over. What I need is a middleware. I am wondering whether I can do it using WCF.

Comment: Sounds like you want persistent objects, I'm afraid this is beyond my expertise. I recall outside of .NET framework others use things like redis/memcached/mongo to handle the serialized objects. I should point out that are .NET db drivers for these NoSQL databases.